# Q: Conditional formatting to highlight the maximum value in each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

What I want is to highlight the largest value in each row through CF. Quick illustration of the structure:

```
   A B C D
1  4 3 2 1
2  3 2 1 4
```

The simplest solution to this would be something like =A1=max($A1:$D1) (and is indeed what comes up when searching for solutions online).  But that means having to go through every row to fix it, changing the row number, and is more than a little bit of a pain.

One thing that momentarily seemed promising was using indirect combined with &row, like this:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())
```

But being (as far as I can understand) forced to not use anchors when using this, it's turned out to be rather useless.

The perfect solution would be one where I can mark all of the rows and have it go through and do this the whole way down, but given that that's unlikely, it'd be nice with at least something akin to that usage of indirect. It would mean I still have to go through and copy paste the formatting on to every row, but that I could at least be spared having to constantly change the row numbers.

Comment: You want to highlight entire selection like, `A1:D2` (as sample data with OP) or partially highlighting like you have mentioned,, `highlight the largest value in each row through CF` ?

Comment: Partial, problem solved now though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select A1 and type Ctrl+A twice (or click the intersection of the row numbers and the column letters in the top-left corner).
2. It is important the whole worksheet is selected and A1 is the 'active cell'.
3. Use Home, Styles, Conditional Formatting, Clear Rules to remove all previous efforts.
4. Use Home, Conditional Formatting, New Rule. Create a new rule based on the following formula,

   ```
   =and(count(a1), a1<>"", a1=max(index($a:$xfd, row(a1), 0)))
   ```
5. Click *Format* and select a **Fill** color. This is the background 'highlight' you were referring to.
6. Click OK to create the new rule.

I've added some error control to ensure that numbers are only referencing other numbers but the `INDEX(..., ROW(...), 0)` is the important part.

Comment: Excellent stuff! With only slight modification this did the trick (the example in the original post was a bit *too* simplified)